# How can i make mercurial to add wildcard for file name

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

we are working on a project, where the angularjs web project is compiled and binaries are stored in hg repo. The problem is angularjs js files are usually compiled with hashing for all binary files. Ex: binary files are suffixed with unique extensions for each file

```
main.1cc794c25c00388d81bb.js, 
polyfills.eda7b2736c9951cdce19.js, 
runtime.a2aefc53e5f0bce023ee.js, 
common.7d1522841bf85b01f2e6.js, 
1.620807da7415abaeeb47.js,
2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3.....etc.
```

The problem is every time a new binary in checkin in hg repo, it is being detected as new file and retained along with old file of same name. So, i need a way to fool the hg repo, to retain the file name but still consider them as old file replacing the previous one.

```
main.1cc794c25c00388d81bb.js  ==> overwrite old main.js 
polyfills.eda7b2736c9951cdce19.js ==> overwrite old polyfill.js 
runtime.a2aefc53e5f0bce023ee.js ==> overwrite old polyfill.js 
common.7d1522841bf85b01f2e6.js ==> overwrite old commom.js
1.620807da7415abaeeb47.js  ==> overwrite old 1.js
2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3 ==> overwrite old 2.js
```

Could any one point out a way, to fool the hg to consider these files are just modification of previous files and not as new files ?
Can hgignore or some other extension be used...

Comment: What does your script for actually committing these to Mercurial look like? `hg mv` or `hg addremove` are the only ways to tell Mercurial about renames.

Comment: hg commit -m "FR xxxxxxxx: Added support for xyz feature" -u username filepath1 filepath2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VCS shall track the state of files. And those are indeed new files. One can argue that those are the old files renamed - which can be recorded by the VCS.

So there are two solutions I see:

1. Record moving the old filenames to the new filenames. `hg addremove --similarity XX` might be of big help here. It will  result in all the files having the new names each time - but if the similarity is good enough it will work nicely. You might need to adjust the `XX` to get a similarity measure (0 ... 100) which works for you best. Adding `--dry-run` for testing purposes might make testing easy. You WILL need to delete the old files before you run `hg addremove` though.
2. Have a pre-commit hook which iterates over *.js files and moves via an appropriate regex *.*.js to *.js omitting the hashing code, effectively overwriting the generic filenames with the newly generated hashed filenames.

Comment: hg addremove --similarity expects numbers

]$ hg addremove --similarity 1.dsfdfdsf.js
abort: similarity must be a number

Comment: Yes, of course it does. And I even explicitly give the number range ...

Comment: `hg addremove` does NOT require a filename argument - it's a catch-all-changes command.

Comment: Thanks, done the second option using a bash script and it works.